# в правильном ли месте вызываю session_start()?

Tags: php

В методах класса иногда приходиться работать с сессиями. 
Вопрос:

лучше в методе класса вызывать session_start() или вынести перед описанием класса?

Т.е.

```
class somaClass {
   public function() {
     session_start();
     ...

   } 
}
```

или

```
session_start();

class somaClass {
   public function() {

     ...

   } 
}
```

Также это относится и при использовании каких-то модулей. Нужно их к методе модули подключать, чтобы использовать классы модулей в методе. Или перед классом вынести?
?

Answer (score 1):

Большой разницы нету, главное что бы сессия начиналась до того как будет отправлен хоть один знак клиенту.
Все зависит от ситуации, если Вы хотите использовать только в одном методе, то лучше в нем прописать старт, если во всем сайте, то лучше с самого начала, ну а если во всем классе, то можно и в конструкторе:

```
class somaClass {
  public function __construct() {
    session_start();
  } 
}
```

Главное знайте, что сессию можно начать только один раз, иначе будет ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` Работать будет в любом случае только до начала вывода каких то данных (или пока сервер не начнет отдавать какие то данные), так что с точки зрения PHP правильного варианта нету.
Но вот с точки зрения архитектуры приложения плохой вариант выносить на каждую страницу начало сессии, потому что должен быть единый механизм выполнения страницы.
 Например пользователь зашел на страницу вызывается класс подключения к базе данных, затем класс работы с сессиями и тд.
 В разных CMS и фреймворках шаги разные и могут меняться но всегда есть некий модуль (класс) который работает с сессиями и потом просто на страницах вызывается. 
Так что лучше делать все это в самом классе.

Answer (score 0):

В современном `PHP` есть рекомендуемые стандарты написания и использования кода для разработчиков, `PSR` - `PHP Standard Recommendation`. И на ваш ответ [`PSR-1`](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) отвечает явным и недвусмысленном образом вот в этой части:

> Files SHOULD either declare symbols (classes, functions, constants, etc.)
>   or cause side-effects (e.g. generate output, change .ini settings, etc.)
>   but SHOULD NOT do both.

Файлы должны либо объявлять новые классы, функции, константы и т.д. либо выполнять какие-то действия. Но нельзя делать и то и другое. Вызов `session_start` с одновременным объявлением класса открыто противоречит этому базовому правилу. То есть фактически так написать можно и это будет работать, но это столь же плохая практика, как глобальные переменные и другие признаки плохого кода.

Должно быть именно:

```
class somaClass {
   public function() {
     session_start();
     ...

   } 
}
```

Возможно вы захотите перед `session_start` проверить, не запущена ли уже сессия была - для этого можно воспользоваться функцией [session_status](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php)